# syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) en prestashop 1.7.6.5

Tags: php, prestashop

estoy usando prestashop 1.7.6.5 y php 7.2.28,estoy monitoreando mi tienda constantemente y me ha arrojado este error **syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)** y me selecciona dos archivos, yo no me he metido con nada de código todo esto es lo que venía por default en el prestashop, es un error que me provoca que mi tienda este un poco lenta.
A continuación dejo fragmentos del código y en las imágenes muestra el error :c

categories.php

```
<?php
   class AdvancedSpeedcategoriesModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
   {
      public $ssl = true;
      private $function_pre = "ajax_";
      private $prefix = 'http://' ;

/**
 * @see FrontController::initContent()
 */

public function initContent()
{
     parent::initContent();

    $token = Configuration::get('as_token');
    
    if($token != Tools::getValue('token'))
        die('Invalid Token');

    Configuration::updateValue('as_cron_regenerate_categories', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));    
    $id_shop = (int)Tools::getValue('as_id_shop');

    $offset = (int)Configuration::get('as_categories_offset_'.$id_shop);
    $limit = (int)Configuration::get('as_categories');

    if($limit < 1)
        $limit = 1;

    $sql = 'SELECT  id_category FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_shop`  '
    if(!empty(Tools::getValue('as_id_shop')))
        $sql .= ' WHERE id_shop ='.(int)$id_shop;
    $sql .= ' LIMIT 1 OFFSET '.(int)$offset;

    $results = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
    $url = '';

    if(!$results)
    {
        Configuration::updateValue('as_categories_offset_'.$id_shop, 0);    
        die(Tools::jsonEncode(array('new_offset' => 0)));
    }

    $langs = Language::getLanguages(true); 
    $link = new Link();

    if($results)
    {
        foreach($results as $res)
        {

            foreach($langs as $lang)
            {
                if($id_shop <= 0)
                    $url =  $link->getCategoryLink((int)$res['id_category'], null, (int)$lang['id_lang']);
                else
                    $url =  $link->getCategoryLink((int)$res['id_category'], null, (int)$lang['id_lang'], null, $id_shop);
        
                $content = AdvancedSpeed::get_url_content_static($url);
            }        
        }

        Configuration::updateValue('as_categories_offset_'.$id_shop, $offset + count($results)  );    
        die(Tools::jsonEncode(array('new_offset' => $offset + count($results) )));
     }
   }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
  require dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php';
  Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

Adjunto imágenes que señalan el error, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias.
[image: error1]

index.php
[image: error2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es en la linea anterior: Falta un punto y coma `;` al final de la instrucción que precede al `if`:

```
$sql = 'SELECT  id_category FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_shop`  ';
if(!empty(Tools::getValue('as_id_shop')))
    $sql .= ' WHERE id_shop ='.(int)$id_shop;
$sql .= ' LIMIT 1 OFFSET '.(int)$offset;
```

Ademas, te recomiendo que encierres las instrucciones correspondientes a los if entre llaves, para demarcar correctamente su contexto. Tambien ayudara a entender mejor la logica a simple vista:

```
if(!empty(Tools::getValue('as_id_shop'))){
    $sql .= ' WHERE id_shop ='.(int)$id_shop;
}
```